# What was Jackie Chan's character's full name in the Rush Hour movies?

Tags: character, rush-hour

In the Rush Hour movies, *Jackie Chan*'s character is referred to as just *Lee*, *Inspector Lee*, *Detective Inspector Lee*, or some variant (e.g. by Rush Hour 2, he's become *Chief Inspector Lee*).

Does he have a full name? On [Wikia](http://rush-hour.wikia.com/wiki/Yan_Naing_Lee) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rush_Hour_(film_series)#Characters) his full name is given as *Yan Naing Lee*. I'm not sure where the source for this is. Is it mentioned in a script? Somewhere in the movies?

**Update**: I'm pretty sure "Yan Naing Lee" is vandalism. It was added in this revision: [Wikipedia Revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rush_Hour_(film_series)&diff=prev&oldid=598230485) together with other vandalized names.

Comment: Considering there's no name on IMDb, I'm guessing that he may not have a full name in the films.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it helps but **in the TV show** the character was named **Jonathan Lee**.  Since Jonathan is clearly not a Chinese name it sounds more like a name adopted to avoid having Americans stumbling over pronouncing (or remembering) his actual name.

**Yan Naing Lee** does seem to be used consistently around the internet but they might all be based on the Wikipedia article (though it seems like an unlikely thing for someone to make up).  If the name wasn't used in the movies, perhaps it appeared that way in the credits.

Comment: Yan Naing and Jonathan seem phonetically connected. This could be a proof of validity (Yan Naing at some point chose to go by Jonathan because it's phonetically similar but much easier to use in the US), but it could also be proof of the vandalism (Yan Naing being a made up name based on the established name of Jonathan)